# Load balancer for kubeapi server while creating the Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create Kubernetes cluster having 1 master and 2 worker nodes by using the tool kubeadm in my on-premise machines. I am following the Kubernetes official documentation for forming the cluster from the following url:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/

After installing all the runtime and completing `before begin pre-requistics` steps, I found in the document as the first step of forming the cluster is `Create load balancer for kube-apiserver`.

**My Doubt**

When I created the single master 3 worker nodes cluster using `kubespray` tool, I did not created any separate load balancer for that. So here when I am following the kubeadm tool, Do I need to create the load balancer actually for forming ?

Why are both tools showing different way, Since I did not created load balancer by using `kubespray` tool. Now I am trying to create cluster with kubeadm tool.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking of load balancers creation during Kubernetes deployment using Kubeadm it depends on your setup. It is not mandatory to setup load balancer. Your cluster will still work, but without load balancing, it's going to be hard to qualify this cluster as HA.

In a single master setup as it is in your case, the master node manages the etcd database, API server, controller manager and scheduler, along with the worker nodes. However, if that single master node fails, all the worker node fail as well and entire cluster will be lost.

Learn more here: [kubernetes-ha-kubeadm](https://velotio.com/blog/2018/6/15/kubernetes-high-availability-kubeadm).

[Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) covers the needs of a life-cycle management for Kubernetes clusters, including self-hosted layouts, dynamic discovery services, etc. Kubespray is more about generic configuration, initial clustering, and bootstrapping.

[Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray) is a good choice when you either are familiar with Ansible or seek a possibility to switch between multiple platforms. If your priority is tight integration with unique features offered by the supported clouds, and you plan to stick with your provider, kops may be a better option.

Deploying a loadbalancer is up to a user and is not covered by ansible roles in Kubespray. By default, it only configures a non-HA endpoint, which points to the access_ip or IP address of the first server node in the kube-master group. It can also configure clients to use endpoints for a given loadbalancer type. More information you can find here: [kubespray-lb](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/ha-mode.md).

Here you have comparision of Kubernetes deployment tools: [Kubernetes Deployment Tools](https://www.altoros.com/blog/a-multitude-of-kubernetes-deployment-tools-kubespray-kops-and-kubeadm/).